# Why is the chat on Meta Stack Overflow not open to new users?

Tags: discussion, reputation, chat, privileges

I do not understand why the chat on Meta SO cannot be open to new users with less than the minimum amount of points. Sometimes it is very hard to quite understand how to pose a question, and I think the guidance of older users on the chat could be used to help the entire community. My question is then why doesn't SE open the chat? What is the logic behind this?

Answer (score 13):

> I think the guidance of older users on the chat could be used to help the entire community.

No. The guidance of established users *in chat* only helps the person who is in chat at that very moment, and is then lost within the chat transcript. The community doesn't benefit from that.

The guidance of established users *through questions and answers on Meta Stack Overflow*, however, has a much bigger chance of also helping others, not only the person asking.

It's the same reason that the other chat sites have a minimum reputation requirement: To prevent new users from using the chat as a replacement for the Q&A site.

Comment: I am thinking more of a time factor, of cutting out less time for editing and  re-editing re sharpening questions based on user response. Sometimes the option for trial and error is important as well. besides, the chat is not completely closed, it will be then open for all as well and have its own transcript. one could also open "beginners only" room which would re direct only relevant users.